# How can I fetch all NFTs within a NEAR account?

Tags: nearprotocol

Assuming all NFTs adhered to the [NEP-171 specification](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html), how can I list all NFTs within an account such as `example.near`?

I see at https://docs.rs/near-contract-standards/latest/near_contract_standards/macro.impl_non_fungible_token_enumeration.html that it ought to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the NEAR CLI, run something like `NEAR_ENV=testnet near view <the contract ID> nft_tokens_for_owner '{"account_id": "<the account ID>"}'`.

See https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Enumeration.html#interface.

`from_index` defaults to 0 and `limit` defaults to unlimited.

Example:

`NEAR_ENV=testnet near view dev-1643292007908-55838431863482 nft_tokens_for_owner '{"account_id": "example.testnet"}'`